# Modify htaccess, to redirect index.php to folder/index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Here is what I currently have in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I am trying to make it so when a visiter visits the website: `www.example.com` instead of loading `index.php` I want it to load `folder/index.php` instead.

I saw something online like this `RewriteRule ^index.php /folder [R=301]` , but that doesnt seem to work.

Is there a way to do this, while keeping the functionality the `.htaccess` currently has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http => https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# load folder/index.php for landing page
RewriteRule ^/?$ folder/index.php [L]
```